# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Rms_Helper_Data' not found in C:\wamp\www\app\Mage.php on line 546

Tags: magento-1.7, module, helper

I realize there are questions just like this one, but none of the answers apply to me so far.

I am building a custom module that works, except the helper class won't load. I'm calling it with `Mage::helper('rms')` and I get

> Fatal error: Class 'NewHope_Rms_Helper_Data' not found in C:\wamp\www\app\Mage.php on line 546

Here's my module config. The observer correctly get triggered after a user successfully registers:

**app/code/local/NewHope/RmsUpdate/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <NewHope_RmsUpdate>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </NewHope_RmsUpdate>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <customer_register_success>
                <observers>
                    <newhope_rmsupdate>
                        <class>newhope_rmsupdate/observer</class>
                        <method>import_new_customer_to_rms</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </newhope_rmsupdate>
                </observers>
            </customer_register_success>
        </events>
        <models>
            <newhope_rmsupdate>
                <class>NewHope_RmsUpdate_Model</class>
            </newhope_rmsupdate>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <rms>
                <class>NewHope_Rms_Helper</class>
            </rms>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/NewHope/RmsUpdate/Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php

class NewHope_Rms_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    ...
}
```

**app/code/local/NewHope/RmsUpdate/Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php

class NewHope_RmsUpdate_Model_Observer
{
    public function import_new_customer_to_rms(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

        //Fatal Error shows up here, when I try to load the rms helper!
        $rms_updated = !!Mage::helper('rms')->CreateRmsUser($customer);

        Mage::log(
            sprintf('%s (%s) registered. RMS Update: %s',
                $customer->getEmail(),
                $customer->getId(),
                $rms_updated ? 'Successful' : 'Failed'),
            null,
            'user-registration.log');
    }
}
```

I have these clues:

1. I experimented with changing the config.xml `<rms>` tag to something arbitrary that I knew was wrong, and the error still remained identical.
2. In between every attempt I manually deleted the var/cache folder, so even though the above points seem like a caching issue, I think they are not.
3. Compilation is disabled already, that's not the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You configured your helper class like this.

```
<helpers>
    <rms>
        <class>NewHope_Rms_Helper</class>
    </rms>
</helpers>
```

So when you request you helper class with `Mage::helper('rms')`, Magento will trace your module, since it defines the helper alias name `rms` and then pick class name associate with it. So in this case, Magento has `NewHope_Rms_Helper`. The next step magento checks, whether you requested in particular helper class name. For example, if you were requested a helper class like `Mage::helper(rms/example)`, then magento will append this `example` part to the class that already picked from your configuration and thus completes the class generation process(Here the class would be `NewHope_Rms_Helper_Example`). However if we didn't specify any specific helper name, then by default, Magento assumes this class name as `Data`. So in your case, Magento forms final helper class as `NewHope_Rms_Helper_Data`.

**The name of the class is an indication to the location where that class should be defined**. That means Magento will now look for your helper in `app/code/local/NewHope/Rms/Helper/Data.php`. If it is not present there, it will look in `app/code/community/NewHope/Rms/Helper/Data.php`. Then again in `app/code/core` directory and then again in `lib` directory. In your case, Magento can't find the helper class. So as a result it will throw an error.(Note location generated is `NewHope\Rms` and not `NewHope\RmsUpdate`).

So the configuration that you need here is

```
<helpers>
    <rms>
        <class>NewHope_RmsUpdate_Helper</class>
    </rms>
</helpers>
```

So this will generate a class `NewHope_RmsUpdate_Helper_Data` and thus first it will look in the location `app/code/local/NewHope/RmsUpdate/Helper/Data.php`. The file content should look like this.

```
<?php
class NewHope_RmsUpdate_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Hope that will give you an idea on what is really happens in the backside

Answer (score 2):

your module helper class name should be in

app/code/local/NewHope/RmsUpdate/Helper/Data.php

```
class NewHope_RmsUpdate_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    ...
}
```

and your xml file should be

```
<helpers>
            <rms>
                <class>NewHope_RmsUpdate_Helper</class>
            </rms>
        </helpers>
```

and call `Mage::helper('rmsupdate');`

Comment: You are right except to the point `Mage::helper('rmsupdate')`. It is wrong. It will generate an error. Take a look on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are only `one issue on helper class declaration in config.xml.`

as your helper class path is `local/NewHope/RmsUpdate/Helper/Data.php`  that means that
your helper base class is `NewHope_RmsUpdate_Helper`.

and that why  **config.xml helper class code look like**

```
<class>NewHope_RmsUpdate_Helper</class>
```

and as you call `helper  at  observer file using   Mage::helper('rms')`    that means  helper `type defined you` as `rms` and `<rms></rms> defined as helper type`

**that helper configuration is**

```
        <helpers>
            <rms>
                <class>NewHope_RmsUpdate_Helper</class>
            </rms>
        </helpers>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, the mistake i did `compilation mode` was enabled when i install extension from `magento connect manager`.

i reinstall the extension after disabled compilation mode `System->Tools->Compilation` and it worked for me without any error. Hope this help other peoples.