# Error on Configuration page

Tags: magento-1.8

When go to admin area and click on system --> configuration I get the below error, how can I fix this? It was working fine before.

Class 'Creare_DynamicSitemap_Helper_Data' not found in /home2/aesaudio/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546

I am using magento 1.8.0.0

Please advise.

Comment: can you put config.xml code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams like you are missing an extension.
Check if the file `app/code/(local or community)/Creare/DymamicSitemap/Helper/Data.php` exists.
If it doesn't you should contact the developer for that extension. If the developer is you, then create the file with this content:

```
class Creare_DynamicSitemap_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {}
```

Also you should clear the cache and disable the compilation if enabled.

Comment: For more details : you can checkout my answer for this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34299/fatal-error-class-mage-rms-helper-data-not-found-in-c-wamp-www-app-mage-php. It will give you an idea.

Comment: @Marius can please check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34336/how-prevent-a-model-data-save-using-save-before/ and i need your point of view

Comment: @Marius : Pardon me. Just put that link to give him what actually happends in backside. If you dont like to put that link here, I will remove that :)

Comment: @AmitBera. You already got an nice answer for that. Let's keep every question clean. That link is not related to this question.

Comment: can i delete my commit from here?

Comment: @Marius, I checked the path and data.php exists. what esle I can do?

Comment: if you have compilation enabled, disable it and recompile if needed. Also clear the cache just in case.

Comment: @Marius Thank you very much, after disabling the compilation and clearing the cache, it worked.  Great job man!

Comment: @Behrouzjaz. Great. I will add this to the answer as well

Answer (score 0):

For any custom configuration under system, Module need helper data file. 
Please check that you have such file in the module : 
app/code/local/Creare/DynamicSitemap/Helper/Data.php

And if you have Data.php file , then also check that helper is defined in the config.xml file (path : app/code/local/Creare/DynamicSitemap/etc/config.xml)